# Hash leaked online

Tags: web-application, hash, data-leakage

Recently I Googled the email address of one of my friends, as I was just curious of what would come up.

Lo and behold, he saw what presumably is his Gmail hash.

It is part of a list of 10,170 email addresses and hashes. First of all, I was kind of surprised that *Google*, of all things, would be compromised (or is it?). Phishing?

He reported a few weeks ago that his email account had been sending strange emails. Something bad is obviously going on. What should he do?

Comment: >I was kind of surprised that Google, of all things

[No one is immune.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Aurora)

Answer (score 6):

Nothing to worry about.  I spot-checked some of the hashes in the file you found, and they're all merely the MD5 checksums of the corresponding (slightly mangled) email addresses.  No password information has been leaked.